# PDF Fillable Forms

Tags: forms

I have created a word document which contains a pdf fillable form as an enclosure.  I am able to double click on the form and it opens up the form to fill.  However, I have asked someone else to try it and they were unable to.  What do I need to do for someone else to open the form?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what OS and/or PDF reader software they are using.

In Windows 10, Microsoft Edge likes to take over as the default PDF viewer for everything, and rarely works properly.

In Linux, the default PDF readers tend to not be compatible with some of the latest versions of created Acrobat PDF files

They may just need to install Adobe Reader, (at the download website, they should uncheck the Optional Offer box), and it should download, install, and associate PDF files with that application.

[Adobe Reader Download](https://get.adobe.com/reader/)